# Icons missing from System Status Area on Gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome, icons

I recently installed Gnome 3.10 and I noticed that some of the icons don't show up on my system status menu.  I can't seem to find any other people having this issue, however if this is a duplicate, please point me in the right direction.

Interestingly enough, the battery and shutdown icons appear, just no others.  Not sure what information is important to help you help me, but ask and you shall receive

Comment: I didn't do anything but when I installed some updates, within those updates, I got my icons to start working.  So while I don't have any "fix" for the issue (should anybody else have this problem), for me, issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I too am having troubles after updating today (10/30/13)
I don't have the gear icon anymore for turning off or rebooting Ubuntu anymore either. Sorry I couldn't help, but I'm also having issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey may be this can work for you.

I have the same problem.. i done some research i found that i added the staging repository. which is unstable.
you go through these commands in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Comment: I tried that but no change.  I have recently noticed there is more than one ppa and I'll be honest, I have no clue which one I used... thinking I may start over

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I added both the staging as well as the next ppas.

But both didn't work. For me, not just the system menu, I didn't have any icons at all, not in Nautilus either. Many GNOME softwares too didn't have their icons.

The inline window buttons on the softwares didn't work either.

Please do help if someone has come up with a solution.